# Plugging USB sound card prevents Windows Screen saver from running

Tags: windows-7, usb, sound-card, screensaver

I'm developing an embedded Windows based device with some extra hardware (an information kiosk).
I need second sound card in the device so I use USB Device like this

[image]

but when I plug it in it prevents Windows screen saver from starting.
When I pull it out the screensaver works again.

I use Windows 7 pro 64-bit. With default driver from Microsoft (version 6.1.7601.17514).
There are no "power management" options on device's proporties dialog :(

Thanks in advance for Your help.